# UICollectionView: expanding cells in a certain position when scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I’m trying to implement an animation in a collection view, the animation is the following:

https://youtu.be/AxbutI_Lrqg

I think that I should override in a custom `collectionviewlayout` class the `func layoutAttributesForElement(in rect: CGRect)` but I'm not sure how to use it... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use look into scroll events **UIScrollViewDelegate** from and update layouts for visible cells.